# Google Places API - pet shelters

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am developing an app for dog owners. I need to get markers on the map such as vets but also dog shelters or pet hotels. I am just curious if it is possible to get the information about dog shelter and pet hotel using this API. I didnt find it in the category list. Probably not but I would like to be sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Here is all the place types in the Google Places API: https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types

Theses are the types you might be interested in:

- `veterinary_care`
- `pet_store`

Comment: Thanks I found those. I was curious if it is possible to find pet shelters. Or do you think veterinary care could include also pet shelters?

Comment: The best way is to try with a known pet shelter. See if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can query search by type. For vets, the type you want is veterinary_care. You can get full list of type in this [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types).
[image]

Comment: Thanks I found those. I was curious if it is possible to find pet shelters. Or do you think veterinary care could include also pet shelters?